# Python Regex - Capture match and previous two lines

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In reference to a previous question
[Python data extract from text file - script stops before expected data match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917720/python-data-extract-from-text-file-script-stops-before-expected-data-match)

How can I capture a match and the previous two lines?
I tried this but get:

unterminated subpattern at position 0 (line 1, column 1)

```
output = re.findall('(.*\r\n{2}random data.',f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: What do you want to match? Repeated groups of two lines, like `line1\n line2\n line1\n line2\n`? Or lines with some spefific text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?:.*\r?\n){2}.*random data.*', s)
```

Note you can't use `re.DOTALL` or `.*` will match up to the end of the input and you will only get the last occurrence.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FCON9C)

**Pattern details**

- `(?:.*\r?\n){2}` - 2 occurrences of a sequence of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (a line)
  - `\r?\n` -  a line ending (`CRLF` or `LF`)
- `.*random data.*` - a line containing `random data` substring.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jhpLsd/1).

Comment: What is the 's'? Gives me: NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: Worked like you said.