# Python - Write list to text file with \n from re.findall

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In reference to a previous question [Python Regex - Capture match and previous two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924025/python-regex-capture-match-and-previous-two-lines/48924091?noredirect=1#comment84874899_48924091)

I am try to write this match to a text file but it seems to write all the matches on 1 line.

Tried these combinations with no luck

```
    output = re.findall(r'(?:.*\r?\n){2}.*?random data.*', f.read())

myfilename.write(str(list(output) + '\n')) # gives me TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
myfilename.write(str(output)) # writes to one line
```

Would I need a for loop to iterate each index to a new line, or am I missing something, it should be matching the CRLLF and keep the original format correct?

Comment: `myfilename.write("\n".join(output))` or `myfilename.write("\r\n".join(output))`

Comment: Ah, thank you, I searched but probably didn't wordn

Comment: It right* thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
with open ("file_here.txt", "r") as fin, open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
    output = re.findall(r'(?:.*\r?\n){2}.*?random data.*', fin.read())
    fout.write("\n".join(output))
```